# Help on Geometric Sequence Problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

The sum of an infinite geometric series with first term
a and common ratio r < 1 is given by $ S_n=a\cdot\dfrac{r^n-1}{r-1} $.
The sum of a given infinite geometric series is $S_{\infty}=200 $ and the
common ratio $r$ is 0.15. What is the second term $a_2$ of this
series?

I'm confused on how to attack,can someone explain it to me? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: For a GP with first term $a$ and common ratio $r$, we have $T_n=ar^{n-1}$ and the sum of the GP upto $n$ terms is $S_n=a\cdot\dfrac{r^n-1}{r-1}$. For infinite GP with $|r|\lt 1$, the sum becomes $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** If $a$ is the first term and $|r|<1$ is the ratio you have
$$a+ar+..+ar^{n}+....=a\frac{1}{1-r}$$

You are told that $a\frac1{1-r} =200$ and what $r$ is . Can you find $a$? Can you find the second term?

Answer (score 0):

$$s=a+aq+aq^2+aq^3+aq^4+...=200\\q=0.15\\$$ to find sum of terms  multiply s by q   , then find $s- qs$  $$s=a+aq+aq^2+aq^3+aq^4+...\\sq= aq+aq^2+aq^3+aq^4+aq^5...\\s-sq=a+(aq-aq)+(aq^2-aq^2)+...=a\\s(1-q)=a\\s=\frac{a}{1-q}\\200=\frac{a}{1-0.15}\\a=170\\$$ now you have a,q
then the second term is $$aq=170(0.15)=25.5$$